# Single thread queue on c#

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0

I have a user interface which generates the Events. So I have the event for example "ButtonPressed" with the arguments.
On event I want to fire time-consuming function "GenerateTableData". Also I want not to block the interface so this function should be on background thread.
After this I can pass the invocation back to the main thread and populate columns.
But if the user presses two times on the Button I don't want to create two threads. Instead I want to interrupt the privious one or waits until it's finished and immediately start another (separate buttons fills table with separate data and we need to show result only from the last one pressed).

And I am stuck with that option. All what seems working to me is casting backgroundworker on each event but I can't prevent it from execution two or more times and can't queued further events.

Please give me an example of solution of this task, I think it should be pretty common.

Here is some pseudocode:

```
void Button1Pressed(args)
{
DoWork(1);
}
void Button2Pressed(args)
{
DoWork(2);
}

void DoWork(int i)
{
BackGroundWorker bg=new BackGroundWorker();
bg.DoWork+= (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) => {e.result=GenerateTable(i)};
bg.RunWorkerCompleted+= (object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) =>{InvokeOnMainThread(()=>{PopulateColumns(e.result)})};
bg.RunWorkerAsync();
}
void PopulateColumns(data)
{
myTable.PopulateWithData(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way to do this, is:

- for each event type, that should be serialized, have a queue
- Raising an event is queuing the event and kicking the queue (see below)
- Wrap your worker in a method, that after finishing the task
- - resets a "worker is running" flag (no locking needed)
- - kicks the queue again

By "Kicking the queue" I mean

- Check the "worker is running" flag, if it is set, do nothing (the ending worker will re-kick)
- Try to dequeue from the locked queue, if it was empty, unlock and do nothing
- So we have work to do: **Before** unlocking the queue, set the "worker is running" flag

Comment: And what is the better way to organize queue? List<Action> or smth?

Comment: Whatever fits best - I typically use a System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T> (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. Tried all day to create workaround and got hard reproducing bugs all the time. The issue was that reading SQLite in internal method was not thread-safe. Finally I got it and now it is ok.